# change text input border color on hit by css

Tags: css

## change text input border color on hit by css

Hello

I've this html field

```
<input type=text value=test id=ff>
```

I am using this css code to set a border

```
#ff{
border:1px #000 solid
}
```

I want to change the border color to ( red ), when I click on the field

For example: The google search field, when you hit the search field to write anything, the border will change to blue

Answer (score 5):

```css
#ff:focus {border-color: #f00; }
```

For IE7 you can use JavaScript (jQuery in particular), for example:

```html
<style>
    #ff:focus,
    #ff.focus {border-color: #f00; }
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script>
$('#ff').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's works fine.. but why it does not work with IE 7?? How i can use it with IE7?

Comment: IE7 is too old browser and just does not support `:focus` pseudoclass. You can use JavaScript if needed. But given that it is not a critical functionality, it's perfectly OK to not care about IE7 in this case.